# hql - LazyCollectionOption.FALSE on query

Tags: hibernate, hql, lazy-initialization

I have this field declaration on my Role class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
private Set<User> users;
```

And my query is like this:

```
"SELECT r FROM Role r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.users u"
```

The users elements size however is always return as 1 (incorrect result) where it should be more than one.
However when I annotated the users field as `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)`, and removed `FETCH` on the query, it returns the collect result.

Any idea why I cant't get it to work using `FETCH` on query? I do not want to resort on `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)` as it will be expensive to call everytime.

**UPDATE:**
My initial workaround is on my DAO to iterate on the return list and call getUsers on each (using this workaround, I was able to retrieve correct count results as well).

```
public List<Role> getRoles(){
   Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.users u");
   List<Role> results = query.list();
   for (Role item: results){
       log.info("size is {}", item.getUsers().size());
   }
}
```

*Will post more code snippet tomorrow* As for the overriden equals and hashCode, I'm using the one generated by IntelliJ IDEA, choosing only the unique fields to include.

Comment: There must be a problem in your entities. Show us their code, espacially their hashCode() and equals() methods if they have one. Also show us the test data on which you're testing this query, the code of the test, and the SQL query generated by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you [implement properly the equals/hashCode](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) methods for all your Entities.
2. The LEFT JOIN FETCH should do the same thing as LAZY=false. Even with an additional select you will still get the Users collection initialized.

Comment: I've tried this one before I went home today, unfortunately even by including only business key on the hashCode and equals, and even using the builders class from apache commons, it still return incorrect set result size.  Will post more code snippet tomorrow from my codes, I've managed to post few updates only today.  By the way, I have some entities where I don't really have a unique and nonupdatable field aside from the auto generated id so I wasn't able to declare my field as @Column(unique = true, updatable = false) as advised, do you think it might cause the incorrect result size? thanks

Comment: As long as the business key is unique you should be fine even without updatable or unique flags set.